# Phrases instead of "How are you?"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

The teachers at school teach us these phrases that we can use instead of **"How are you?"** which of them are natural English and commonly used and which are uncommon?

I know surely that **"How do you do?"** is just a very formal **"Hello!"** but somehow our teachers not know of this!

Also **"What's up?"** and **"What is up?"** are synonyms, the latter, I think, is rare and uncommon.

I also think that **"Wazap?"** and **"Wassup?"** are too informal and mostly black people use them.

P.s. I'm not in school.

[image]

Comment: How's it hangin?

Comment: I have never heard anybody say "How wags the world?" and the only references I can find to it are either extremely old or from people who apparently used the same Russian textbook.

Comment: "What gives?" is in use but it means something completely different; it is not a greeting, but more like a complaint.  You would use it like, "Hey, the concert was supposed to start at 3, but it's four-thirty now and the doors still aren't open.  What gives?"

Comment: "What's the rumpus?" sounds weird as a greeting to me, because *rumpus* means "a disturbance, an uproar", but maybe it's in use in other English-speaking countries.  "How far?" just sounds bizarre.  If somebody said that to me as a greeting, I would give them a blank stare and a "Huh?"

Answer (score 3):

**Informal, common**

What's new?

What's up?

What's happening?

How are you getting along? (not standard but not uncommon)

How goes it?

How's life?

How are things?

How's it going?

---

**Neither formal nor informal, common**

How are you?

How are you doing?

---

**Formal, common**

How do you do? (very formal)

---

**I have never heard anyone say in greeting:**

What gives?*

Wazap?

What's the rumpus?

How wags the world?

How is the world using you?

How fares it?

How's by you?

---

- What gives? - This is a question you ask someone when you want them to explain something. "The microwave is disgusting, what gives?" "This mail you handed me is already open, what gives?"

Comment: One thought I had about "How are you getting along?" is that it's sometimes used when you know the other person has just gone through some trying ordeal, such as a major illness, or the death of a close relative. It's a way of asking how the person is handling the crisis.

Comment: How do you do? is a greeting and not a question, although the question mark belongs there.